# How to setup Team Development for a Mathematica project?

Tags: development

I am currently working solo on a project that consists of package files, munit tests, notebooks and .xls files. I use Wolfram Workbench as an IDE. I want to collaborate with others on this project. Ideally I would like to do this as I am used to do with Java: dump everything in cvs ( any system will do ) on the net and then check/out, check/in with one person as a repository admin.

**Question: How should I do this with a Mathematica project? Do I need Workbench plugins? What are the particular pitfalls, if any?**

Comment: This is why I use Eclipse + Wolfram plugin (+ Subclipse plugin + ...) rather than the Workbench.

Comment: That's more of a teaser like I have a setup but I am not giving it away.

Comment: I think @b.gatessucks answers your question. Just start using Eclipse with the Workbench plugin instead of the Workbench IDE.

Comment: Did you know that TortoiseSVN as well as some other Tortoise clients derived from it (e.g. TortoiseHg) have [support for diffing notebook files](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/search?q=mathematica&origq=mathematica&btnG=Search+Trunk) using the Mathematica front end?

Comment: @Szabolcs - your link doesn't work. Sounds interesting though.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Seems to be link-rot.  It was just a link to the commit adding the functionality.  Several of these Tortoise... clients on Windows will automatically use Mathematica to diff notebooks, no extra setup is needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I got my setup :

1. download Eclipse, along with all the plugins you need (svn, cdt, texlipse, ...), from www.eclipse.org ;
2. download Eclipse plugin for workbench from http://www.wolfram.com/services/premiersupport/workbench.cgi : you will have a choice between platforms : Windows, Macintosh, Linux, Eclipse;
3. choose the last one (eclipse) and save the file somewhere;
4. open Eclipse, then Help->Install New Software -> Add and browse to the location of the file you saved.

The Wolfram plugin will give you all the features of the Workbench : code editor, documentation builder, webMathematica, MUnit package as you can see from the screenshot below .
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suppose I already have the Wolfram Plugin, or is that different from the Workbench ?

Comment: I think it's a different download from Wolfram's website.

Comment: I followed your link in the other answer and that pointed to a download of the Workbench. - I read once that the Workbench is a customized Eclipse using the same Wolfram plugin you mentioned, BUT... I am not sure. And as you say there might be a seperate download anyway.

Comment: The link offers 4 choices for downloading : the first three are the Workbench for the different platforms (Windows, Macintosh, Linux). The last one is called "Eclipse" and it's the plugin for the regular Eclipse I was mentioning above.

Comment: While the link is not likely to go away, as it is on SO, could you summarize it here?

Answer (score 15):

Here is a take for those using only the *Mathematica* front end and git. I recently starting using git so that I can work with other collaborators. It was relatively simple since we were using notebooks to create figures from imported data that was located in the same directory. In this case all the notebooks started with the line:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
```

The problem happened when we needed to use other packages. I did not want to bother them with getting their own copy and to put it in `$UserBaseDirectory`. I figured instead that I can create a folder in the git project were I could place all of the external packages that we need and use them. Now we just need to tell *Mathematica* where to look for those files. Initially my collaborator used the absolute path: `/Users/username/path/to/gitproject/mathematica/`. This path was obviously not going to work for me. The way to do this is to declare a relative path. Since we are working in git we can use

```
Import["!git rev-parse --show-toplevel", "Text"]
```

to obtain the path to the git project. Now we can create relative paths. So now
our Notebooks started with this:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
MMAROOT = ToFileName[{
    Import["!git rev-parse --show-toplevel", "Text"], 
    "mathematica", "applications"}
];
If[! MemberQ[$Path, MMAROOT], PrependTo[$Path, MMAROOT]]
```

This however was getting annoying since we had to copy and paste this code every time we created a new notebook. Instead I came up with this function and put in the file `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`.

```
(** User Mathematica initialization file **)
EMPH[a_, style_: "TI"] := ToString[Style[a, style], StandardForm]
LINK[label_, url_] := ToString[Hyperlink[label, url], StandardForm]
USAGE[str_, inputs__] := ToString[StringForm[str, inputs], StandardForm]
GitSetup::usage = USAGE["GitSetup[`1`, `2`, ...] sets the working \
directory to the directory of the calling notebook and appends the \
inputs to `3`. The input paths are relative to the git root \
directory.", EMPH["path1"], EMPH["path2"], 
LINK["$Path", "paclet:ref/$Path"]]
GitSetup[input__] := Module[{path, gitpath, tmp},
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    gitpath = Import["!git rev-parse --show-toplevel", "Text"];
    path = {input};
    Do[
        tmp = ToFileName[{gitpath, path[[i]]}];
        If[! MemberQ[$Path, tmp],
            PrependTo[$Path, tmp];
        ],
        {i, Length[path]}
    ];
    $Path
]
```

Now I only bother my collaborators to put that file so that every time they start *Mathematica* they have access to the function `GitSetup`. Now every notebook starts with

```
GitSetup["mathematica/applications"]
```

And in case they forget what this function does:

[image: GitSetup usage]

Now we can add or develop packages related only to the project we are working on without having to worry about any paths and without even having to call `SetDirectory`.

### Skip the function arguments:

If your git project contains source files from other languages it might be convenient to create a `.bashrc` in the root git folder. This bash file should apply to all the collaborators of the group and not just yourself (you have `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` for that). This is how the `.bashrc` file looks
in the git directory (placed in the same folder as `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`):

```bash
# Bash commands related to the git project
export GITROOT="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PR=$GITROOT
export PATH=$PR/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$PR/main/python:$PR/python:$PYTHONPATH
export MATLABPATH=$PR/main/matlab:$PR/matlab:$MATLABPATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$PR/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$PR/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export MMA_PATH=$PR/main/mathematica:$PR/mathematica
```

Whenever we want to work in the project we `source` that file and all the packages in the project will be available. In this way we can specify where we want *Mathematica* to look for packages in the git project by creating an enviroment variable. I called it `MMA_PATH` and added two paths to it. Now the `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` file looks as follows:

```
(** User Mathematica initialization file **)
BeginPackage["mathrc`"]

Begin["`Private`"]
EMPH[a_, style_: "TI"] := Module[{},
    ToString[Style[a, style], StandardForm]
]
LINK[url_, label_:Style["\[RightSkeleton]", "SR"]] := Module[{},
    ToString[Hyperlink[url, label], StandardForm]
]
USAGE[str_, inputs__] := Module[{},
    ToString[StringForm[str, inputs], StandardForm]
]
End[]

GitSetup::usage = `Private`USAGE["GitSetup[] sets the working \
directory to the directory of the calling notebook and appends the \
paths defined by `1` to `2`. The definition of `1` is found in the \
.bashrc file in the git root directory. In the event that you are \
not working in a git directory then an attempt will be made to look \
for the .bashrc file by looking in the parent directories up to your \
home directory.",
   `Private`EMPH["$MMA_PATH", "Input"],
   `Private`LINK["$Path", "paclet:ref/$Path"]
]

Begin["`Private`"]
GitSetup[] := Module[{gitpath, mmapath, path, parent, bashrc},
    parent = NotebookDirectory[];
    SetDirectory[parent];
    gitpath = Import[
        "!git rev-parse --show-toplevel", "Text"
    ];
    If[gitpath != "",
        bashrc = FileNameJoin[{gitpath, ".bashrc"}];
        ,
        bashrc = FileNameJoin[{parent, ".bashrc"}];
        While[!FileExistsQ[bashrc],
            parent = ParentDirectory[parent];
            bashrc = FileNameJoin[{parent, ".bashrc"}];
            If[parent == $HomeDirectory,
                Break[];
            ]
        ]
    ];
    mmapath = Import[
        "!source " <> bashrc <> "; echo $MMA_PATH", "Text"
    ];
    path = StringSplit[mmapath, ":"];
    Do[
        If[!MemberQ[$Path, path[[i]]],
            PrependTo[$Path, path[[i]]];
        ],
        {i, Length[path]}
    ];
    $Path
]
End[]

EndPackage[];
```

Now the notebooks start with `GitSetup[]` and we are ready to work.

### Deployment for non-git collaborators

If it so happens that some of your collaborators refuse to use git and prefer to use something say like dropbox, then the notebooks you produce with the command `GitSetup[]` will also work for them.

To share your git repository with such collaborators with dropbox all you have to do is create a symbolic link from your git repository to a folder in dropbox. For instance

```bash
ln -s /path/to/git/repo/name_of_repo /path/to/folder/in/dropbox/name_of_repo
```

Since your repository already contains a `.bashrc` file all the notebooks in your repository will also work for your non-git collaborator because the `GitSetup` function will look for such file the momement it realizes that the user does not have `git`.

**Edit:** For those who have been following the edits to the `init.m` file, I have included the `GitSetup` function inside a package so that the names in the `Global` context does not get polluted when you start `Mathematica`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're already using Workbench, I don't see any reason to switch to Eclipse+plug-in.  CVS is included in Workbench, and you can still add additional plug-ins as needed.

Likewise, if you're already using Eclipse for non-Mathematica work, I'd just install the Workbench plugin.

As far as I'm concerned, the main difference is the icon.  (There are of course other differences, but mostly they don't affect my use of Workbench.)

Comment: Sometimes a different version of Eclipse than the one packaged with Workbench is required.