# How to combine notebook into one cell

Tags: notebooks

I want to have my entire notebook be a conditional while statement. However, I don't want to merge all of my cells together, as it is a long and detailed process. Is there a way to create another cell that encompasses all of the smaller cells in my notebook?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to have my entire notebook be a conditional while statement?"  Have you looked at Cell Groups?

Comment: Just guesswork, but this could be useful: [Creating Mathematica packages](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/131). Otherwise, your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to be able to combine all of my original cells into a larger cell without losing the smaller subcells. I don't know how topics in Cell groups would help if I am trying to span across multiple cells to create another cell. @Mr.Wizard

Comment: Is is possible to simple rerun the notebook if, at the end, a certain condition is not met?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
 If[condition, NotebookEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]]
```

I'd suggest its somewhat cleaner to create a second 'control' notebook with some code similar to this:

```
 While[condition , NotebookEvaluate[First@Notebooks["Untitled-4"]]
```

Comment: your code seems to work, but I cannot figure out how to get the output of my cells to show.

Comment: I don't follow that - the output appears in the notebook same as if you did select-all;shift-enter.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping power is controlled by the Option `CellGroupingRules`, frequently defined in the style sheet system.  The outermost Cell style by default is `Title` and has `CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 0}`.  Smaller values group larger values, and `0` is the smallest that is normally present.  If you create a new Cell with negative value in this place it will group all below it.

For example if I create a new Cell (as entered in the **Show Expression** view):

```
Cell["Entire Notebook", "Title", CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", -10}]
```

It will group everything under it, e.g.:

[image]