# working with notebooks ('looping' a notebook and storing the results of each step in another notebook)

Tags: notebooks, save

A notebook contains a series of numerical calculations (numerical integrations, numerical solution of systems of equations etc).

Many parameters are involved.

The final result is in the form of a list; let's called Reslst.

Say, that I want for a specific parameter to evaluate ten times this notebook (each evaluation will give different Reslst) and stored the results (i.e. Reslst) in a new notebook automatically, without copy/paste.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Update

I will try to be more specific.
Let's call the original notebook EVALUATIONS.

This notebooks contains values numerical calculations which eventually result in the following

```
Keff = Km + (cp*(-Km + Kp)*(3*Km + 4*Mm))/(3*Km + 
      3*(1 - cp)*(-Km + Kp) + 4*Mm); 

Meff = Mm + (5*cp*Mm*(3*Km + 4*Mm)*(-Mm + Mp))/(5*Mm*(3*Km + 4*Mm) + 
      6*(1 - cp)*(Km + 2*Mm)*(-Mm + Mp)); 

Reslst = {cp, Keff, Meff};
```

Apart from cp the Km, Kp etc are obtained from the aforementioned numerical calculations.

What I want now is the following.

Starting with cp=0, evaluate 11 times the notebook for 0<=cp<=1 (i.e. with 0.1 steps) and stored the list `Reslst` in a another notebook called it RESULTS.
The whole procedure will be done automatically. No need for Copy/Paste; no need for press SHIFT+ENTER more than one time.

I read the suggestions in the comments, but since I haven't worked with these features (actually I did not know their presence) I would appreciate bigger help.

Comment: take a look at `CreateDocument[]` et al

Comment: If you must loop over a (multiple cell ) notebook see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50570/how-to-combine-notebook-into-one-cell.

Comment: Strangely, it appears to be a hard thing?! Even in MathGroup I did not find any answers in relevant queries...

Comment: automated  evaluation of whole notebooks is not the usual way of working with mathematica. Better to simply use a loop construct. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if the notebook contains hundreds of cells, where should I add the loop construct?

Comment: It seems that I found a solution, using something I found here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/$20results$20in$20another$20notebook|sort:relevance/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/TdXiUU_6_vo/v9ge-SNrsMwJ

Comment: that's what I meant by "if you must":  if its really too much trouble to convert a notebook to a properly structured form you can use `NotebookEvaluate` to repeatedly evaluate the whole thing.

Comment: George, it goes beyond question, that your suggestion above and belisarius as well, was the reason to search about things that I ignored their presence, until today:-)! Thank you very much!

Comment: You should consider converting your notebook into a package (.m, more or less   a WL script). Then repeated evaluation will be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

elaborating on the answer referenced in my comment,
here is a self-evaluating notebook..

[image]

Comment: George, great staff! Thanks!