# Can I code a conditional jump between cells in a notebook?

Tags: programming

How can I code the *Mathematica* equivalent of the following pseudocode:

```
if[condition] ... goto[label_1] ... else goto[label_2]
```

where `label_1` and `label_2` are in different cells. I've trawled the documentation, the web and this SE, but can't find anything.

Specifically, I'm trying to compute the flow field of different types of fluids. The computation depends on the nature of the fluid, so, I want to say: if *fluid_type_1*, do *algorithm_1*, if *fluid_type_2*, do *algorithm_2*. Easy to do in Fortran, Python, etc., but I'd like to do it in *Mathematica* -- which is more accessible to my students.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I would not try to do this at the notebook level.  You can *define* two functions, then call the appropriate one based on the condition.  This is easier and more flexible than trying to evaluate a certain cell based on the condition.  Also, it doesn't depend on one particular notebook and its structure.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that is making you ponder coding gymnastics of this sort?

Comment: To put it clearer. Perhaps (almost surely) it can be done in some twisted way. But it is very, very far from the recommended Mathematica programming practices. If you care to explain your case someone will show you a much better alternative.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66159/2079

Comment: I'm trying to compute the stress state in hyperlastic materials, given the deformation state.   The computation depends on the nature of the material, so, I want to say:

Comment: It can be done, but don't do it.  If you want to make it accessible to your students, don't do it.  Instead do what Patrick suggests.  "Easy to do in Fortran, Python, etc but I'd like to do it in Mathematica - which is more accessible to my students." <- Python and Fortran don't have cells, and Python doesn't have `goto`.  Do you mean a conditional, like `if`?  If so, it works the same in Mathematica, just don't split it into multiple cells. Expressions cannot be split between cells.

Comment: Note that Mathematica doesn't depend on the notebook interface either, it can function without it. Programs can be (and are) written in plain text. Making a program dependent on notebook magic will make it impossible to transfer it to plain text (e.g. a package) and will make it difficult to transfer it between notebooks.

Answer (score 10):

Don't do this. You should never ever need this.

Instead, define `f[x_, algorithm_]` with a flag for which algorithm to use. This is roughly how all built-in functions work, though they usually use `Option`s instead. Same principle, though. For example, say `condition` were `5>6`, and you wanted to perform the Tarragon transform if `condition` were true, and the Manifesto transform otherwise.

```
f[x_, "Tarragon"] := x+5
f[x_, "Manifesto"] := x/2

If[5>6, f[1, "Tarragon"], f[1, "Manifesto"]]
```

You could even push the boat out and define two separate functions:

```
tarragon[x_] := x+5
manifesto[x_] := x/2

If[5/6, tarragon, manifesto][1]
```

As an aside, you may find `Label` useful (if you put everything into one cell, because it only works within `CompoundExpression`s). Never use `Label`, it's extremely bad practice.

```
f[a_] := Module[{x = 1., xp},
  Label[begin];
  If[Abs[xp - x] < 10^-8, Goto[end]];
  xp = x;
  x = (x + a/x)/2;
  Goto[begin];
  Label[end];
 x]
```

Comment: Sometimes I find it more readable to do `f["Tarragon"][x_]:=...` and etc. +1

Comment: @N.J.Evans `f[x_, ...]["Tarragon"] := ...` would be more versatile, due to the fact that one cannot define `Hold*` attributes that affect subvalues.

Comment: I have found use for `Label`, admittedly I was symbolically evaluating Fortran code, but I found a use. To say it is bad practice, though, is open for [debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism). However, it is primarily useful in multiple exit points which can be easily handled by either a `Catch`/`Throw` block or restructuring you code to be more functional, so it is likely not useful in Mathematica. Oh, and +1.

Comment: Your example is better written: `f[a_] := Module[{x = a/2., xp = a}, Label[begin]; If[Abs[xp - x] < 1.*^-8, Return[x]]; xp = x; x = .5 (x + a/x); Goto[begin]]`

Comment: I just copy-pasted it from the docs - I think it's there for pedagogical value rather than anything else.