# Symbol resolution for contexts inside packages

Tags: packages, contexts

Say I create `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/MyPackage/init.m` containing:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
Symbol1 = 1;
Begin["`MyContext`"];
Symbol2 = 2;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

When I run Mathematica:

- `Symbol1` resolves to `` MyPackage`Symbol1 `` and is colored black, indicating it has a value assigned.
- `` MyContext`Symbol2 `` does not resolve, but `` MyPackage`MyContext`Symbol2 `` does. However, there is no autocompletion and the symbol is colored blue (indicating no value assigned) even after evaluation.

Is it possible to configure my package such that `` MyContext`Symbol2 `` will resolve and have all the front-end niceties?

Comment: I believe this question is answered here: [(29324)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324)  (I am sorry no one directed you to this Q&A sooner.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to expose a symbol which is defined within a private context is to define a usage string outside the private context, as in

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
Symbol1 = 1;
Symbol2::usage = "Symbol2 is a test symbol";
Begin["`MyContext`"];
Symbol2 = 2;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Actually, any mention of the symbol inside the package but outside the private context will do the job, but there is a long-standing good practice to use this requirement as an excuse to define a usage string.