# Symbol appears in multiple contexts when load two packages with unique function names

Tags: programming, contexts

I have two packages "packageA`" and "packageB`".  The function names across packageA and packageB are unique.  No two functions have the same name.

When I issue the commands in a notebook:

```
Needs["packageA`"];
Needs["packageB`"];
```

I get a Symbol appears in multiple contexts for every function in packageB`.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to load two packages at the same time?
2. Is there any way to have two packages with the same function names (is it really possible to have local methods in a package)?
3. Is there anything in Mathematica that works in a similar fashion to a namespace in .net languages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is all covered in the documentation. To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, just call `Needs` or `Get` more than once.
2. Yes, by setting up contexts correctly
3. Yes, but in Mathematica they are called [Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html).

The issue is likely to be that you did not use a standard package structure to write your packages, including the `` Begin["Private`"] ``.

See the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/creating-mathematica-packages) for more information.