# The problem with "Symbol appears in multiple contexts" when loading package with same function name in subpackages

Tags: packages, contexts

There is a similar question about this, 8 years ago!,  but the answer there does not really give what to do. The answer just says yes one can use same function name in different packages but has use the contexts *correctly* to do that. Ok, But how?

[symbol-appears-in-multiple-contexts-when-load-two-packages-with-unique-function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65609/symbol-appears-in-multiple-contexts-when-load-two-packages-with-unique-function)

Adding comment there now for clarification, is not too useful and will not likely be seen. So I am posting this question again asking for a possible direct simple solution to this problem from the package experts.

I searched for last 2 hrs and read many posts and I see no one giving simple solution other one I found and will show it below, but I am not sure if this what I should do or not as I am  not too familiar with writing packages.

Here is the problem again. I want to have 2 packages `a` and `b` both below **same context** name `nma`.    So there will be

```
nma`a`
nma`b`
```

packages. These are loaded from the notebook using the command

```
<<nma`
```

The problem is that each package `a` and `b` has public function called `foo`. And this causes the problem.  I set up the package layout as described in many posts, under `$BaseDirectory/Applications` using this layout

```
          Application/
            nma/
              Kernel/init.m
              a.m
              b.m
```

Where init.m is

```
<<nma`a`
<<nma`b`
```

And `a.m` is

```
BeginPackage["nma`a`"] 
Unprotect @@ Names["nma`a`*"]; 
ClearAll @@ Names["nma`a`*"]; 
 
foo::usage = "foo[x]" 
Begin["`Private`"]      
foo[x_] := Module[{}, x^3];      
End[]; 
Protect @@ Names["nma`a`*"]; 
EndPackage[];
```

and `b.m` is

```
BeginPackage["nma`b`"] 
Unprotect @@ Names["nma`b`*"]; 
ClearAll @@ Names["nma`b`*"]; 
 
foo::usage = "foo[x]" 
Begin["`Private`"]      
foo[x_] := Module[{}, x^2];      
End[]; 
Protect @@ Names["nma`b`*"]; 
EndPackage[];
```

Now when doing, from notebook

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One solution I saw (which I lost the link to now, but will try to find it) says to solve this problem is to change `init.m` to the following

```
<<nma`a`
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
<<nma`b`
```

And now doing

```
<<nma`
```

no longer produce this warning.

my question is, is this the correct way to solve this? Should one then insert `$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;` between each package they load in `init.m`? Like this:

```
<<nma`a`
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
<<nma`b`
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
<<nma`c`
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
<<nma`d`
$ContextPath = Rest@$ContextPath;
<<nma`e`
```

I wanted to make sure about this and if there is a better way to handle this. It is strange that same function name but in two different packages should clash with each others like this.

I put the whole nma tree above in one zip file if it helps. Here is the [zip file](https://12000.org/tmp/10012022/nma.zip).

Comment: Thanks for both great answers. I wish I can accept both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am often annoyed by the shadowing message, because it ends up being issued when you don't ever have the two symbols on the context path at the same time but in this case I think the message is correct and usually helpful.

If you do not want all of the symbols in `` nma`a` ``  available on the context path then you should not call `Get` on it.  To read in a file that declares a package without also adding those symbols to your context path use something like

```
getFile[file_]:=Internal`InheritedBlock[{$ContextPath},Get[file]]
getFile["nma`a`"]
getFile["nma`b`"]
```

With the above in your `init.m` file I can call

```
<< nma`
```

without message, and I can call either `` nma`a`foo `` or `` nma`b`foo `` without error so long as I use their full name.

Answer (score 4):

The answer will depend on the desired behavior. I see two options:

- One can ignore the warning message. This makes sense for people who understand that shadowing occurs and understand that full names need to be used to access shadowed public symbols, but still want the convenience of accessing non-shadowed public symbols via their short names. To more conveniently access shadowed symbols, one can introduce shorthands such as `` fooA = packageA`foo ``, or use [`$ContextAliases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextAliases.html).
- One can remove packages manually from `$ContextPath`, as OP suggests. To understand the purpose of this, see the documentation of [`EndPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EndPackage.html). The thing to be aware of in this case is that for a package removed from `$ContextPath`, no public symbol can be accessed via its short name. On the upside, this approach removes the danger of unintentionally getting the wrong symbol.

In either case, the warning message can be turned off using, for example, `Off[General::shdw]`.