# how to move package from FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}] to another location/disk and have kernel/init.m work as before?

Tags: packages, pathfinding

After spending more than 1 hr on this, and looking at many questions, I give up as I am not able to figure a solution.

I have my current package in the standard location given by `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` which on windows is

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications
```

My package is `nma`, so I have in the above the standard set up of `nma.m` and `kernel\init.m` where init.m loads all the files using `Get`.

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\nma\nma.m
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\nma\A.m
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\nma\B.m    

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\nma\kernel\init.m
```

The above is all working fine. I can do

```
 <<nma`
```

From any notebook, and all the files in the package are loaded just fine.

But I do not like to keep my software on the C drive. My backup software only backups another drive. So I wanted to move `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\nma\` to say `G:\` drive and the whole tree to say `G:\mathematica_version\code\nma\`. But when I did this, and made sure to open the notebook in same folder and made sure to do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` so that current directory is the above where all the files including `kernel` folder are, now when I do

```
 <<nma`
```

It no longer loads all the files in the package, it only loads `nma.m`, because I assume it does not use `init.m` in the `kernel` folder anymore, where `init.m` was loading all the other .m files.

It seems `application_name/kernel/init.m` is only used when the package lives in the standard location `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications` ? Is this true?

**My question is**, how to copy `Applications\nma\...` from C drive to any other location and have

```
<<nma`
```

work the same as before? i.e. as if the package was in the standard location?

I tried my other things, like `AppendTo[$Path,"G:\\mathematica_version\\code\\nma"]` but this had no effect.

So currently after moving the package to the different location, I have to now manually do a `Get` on each file. This is something that `init.m` was doing before. i.e. I am doing this now

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
 Get["nma.m"]
 Get["A.m"]
 Get["B.m"]
 etc...
```

for each .m file. I would prefer to have init.m do this as before if possible.

**Update**

I also tried the following. Changed `$UserBaseDirectory` to point to the location in the other disk. Removed all the `Application\` folder and moved it to the new location.   But this did not work. When I did

```
<<nma`
```

It did not load the package.   To change `$UserBaseDirectory` I had to do the following

```
 Unprotect[$UserBaseDirectory]
 $UserBaseDirectory="new path here"
 Protect[$UserBaseDirectory]
```

So I copied the Application folder back to where it was.  I thought may be by moving the whole Application tree and changing `$UserBaseDirectory` will make it work. May be I did not do it right, I looked at option inspector and did not see where `$UserBaseDirectory` is defined.  Is it ok to change `$UserBaseDirectory` to new location? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the only way to change `$UserBaseDirectory` is via the [`MATHEMATICA_USERBASE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html) environment variable, everything else is too late in the launch process. Another approach would be to use symbolic links to have the files stored on the data drive, but still have them accessible from the usual location on the C drive. Finally: Why do you even need both an init.m and a main package file? Why not have both in one? As far as I am aware, Mathematica only loads the first of those files it finds?

Comment: @LukasLang I need `init,.m` because of the way the files are loaded is not the default way.  I am using this method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274189/the-problem-with-symbol-appears-in-multiple-contexts-when-loading-package-with)  so I need `init.m` for that. But for now, I load all the subpackages manually as I showed. Not a big deal. But will be nice if I can move Application tree to my data disk instead of having it on C drive. Will look at the link you gave. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for `Get` (Wolfram Desktop 13.2 on macOS) states

[image]

which I always interpreted that the files are searched *in that order* and that the first file found stops the search. If that interpretation is right, then the new behavior you are observing is correct.

It's unclear why then you would have things working under the old setup - I would put my money on some undocumented special handling of system directories due to some legacy reasons.

**Update**. Here is a little experiment I did (I have `~/Documents/packages/` added to my `$Path`) which proves my hypothesis above:

```
createMX[path_, num_] := Block[{myPrint},
  If[num < $minNum, Return[]];
  myPrint[] := Print[num];
  DumpSave[path, myPrint]]

createWL[path_, num_] := Block[{},
  If[num < $minNum, Return[]];
  WriteString[path, "myPrint[] := Print[" <> ToString@num <> "]"];
  Close[path]]

createContext[dir_, context_, min_ : 1] := 
 Block[{prefix = dir <> context, $minNum = min},
  createMX[prefix <> ".mx", 1];
  createWL[prefix <> ".wl", 2];
  CreateDirectory[prefix <> "/"];
  CreateDirectory[prefix <> "/Kernel/"];
  createWL[prefix <> "/Kernel/init.wl", 3];
  createWL[prefix <> "/init.wl", 4];
  createWL[prefix <> ".m", 5];
  createWL[prefix <> "/Kernel/init.m", 6];
  createWL[prefix <> "/init.m", 7];
  ]

createContext["~/Documents/packages/", "mytest"]

<< mytest`

myPrint[] (* 1 *)

createContext["~/Documents/packages/", "mytest1", 3]

<< mytest1`

myPrint[] (* 3 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried my other things, like `AppendTo[$Path,"G:\\mathematica_version\\code\\nma"]` but this had no effect.

The location you need to add to `$Path` is one level higher: `"G:\\mathematica_version\\code"`. After this, try `` FindFile["nma`"] `` to verify that it returns `"G:\\mathematica_version\\code\\nma\\Kernel\\init.m"`.

As Victor points out in his answer, the system will look for:

- `nma/Kernel/init.m`
- `nma.m`

Note that it does *not* look for `nma/nma.m`.  The package can either be in a single file (`nma.m`) or in a directory organized in a standard way (`nma` directory containing `init.m` in one of the standard locations).