# What is the current structure of a simple package?

Tags: packages, documentation

Currently, from a variety of examples, and (mostly) the template generated by [my IDE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7232?pr=), I get:

```
(* Mathematica Package *)

(* :Title: MyPkg *)
(* :Context: MyPkg` *)
(* :Author: Me *)
(* :Date: 2015-12-17 *)

(* :Package Version: 0.3 *)
(* :Mathematica Version: 10.3 *)
(* :Copyright: (c) 2015 Me *)
(* :Keywords: *)
(* :Discussion: *)


(* USAGE:

    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    Get["MyPKg`"];

*)

BeginPackage["MyPkg`"]

Unprotect@@Names["MyPkg*"];
ClearAll@@Names["MyPkg*"];

MyPkg::usage = "Test package";

f::usage = "Solve it";
g::usage = "Show the puzzle";


(* ::Package:: *)

Begin["`Private`"]


(* ******************** Public exported functions and definitions *)

f[x_] := p[x]/2;
g[x_] := f[x] + q[x];

(* ******************** Internal supporting functions and definitions *)

p[x_] = x + 5;
q[x_] = x + 10;

End[] (* `Private` *)


EndPackage[]
```

But I'm confused about whether this is the right structure, or whether it does what I expect it to. Specifically:

1. Is it really necessary or correct to define the package name in so many places? In the example, I have it in `Title`, `Context`, and `BeginPackage`, which seems redundant and prone to error.
2. How do I ensure that reimports of my package (with `Get` reliable clear the symbols defined there before defining them again. I'v seem several different approaches, but while, `Unprotect@@Names["MyPkg*"];` and 
   `ClearAll@@Names["MyPkg*"];` seem the most common, the don't seem to do anything. (And note again: I've had to specify the package name explicitly; is there a way to avoid that?)
3. What is `(* ::Package:: *)` for? Where should it go? I can't find that documented anywhere.
4. And what good is does the distinction among public, private, and exported symbols do anyway? If I `` ?"GCHQ`*" `` I see *all* of them, even those that are private or local!
5. Some examples show ("protected") definitions between `End[] (* Private *)` and `EndPackage[]`; what goes there?

Any other tips on the correct structure for a package would also be appreciated. I can't seem to find consistent documentation on this, and much of what I can find is surpassingly old.

Comment: Reading this book: [**Programming in Mathematica** 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Mathematica-Edition-Roman-Maeder/dp/020185449X) written by Roman Maeder, who is the key developer of *Mathematica* of version 1.

Comment: You've seen [Creating Mathematica packages](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/131) ?

Comment: @YvesKlett: Yes, and?

Comment: You are aware that comments are marked with (* *)? That should answer questions 1 and 3.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Which ones?

Comment: Just wanted  to make sure you don't miss out on available information that may available there.

Comment: @rax What do you mean?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Are you saying that `(* ::Package:: *)`, for example has no meaning and is just a comment like any other?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @YvesKlett: Ah, ok; I just wondered if I'd missed something specific there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: So none or those things that look like keywords that might be extracted by some tool or doc-generator or indexer — e.g., `:Keywords:` or `::Package::` are used for anything?

Comment: It easily might be, but they're not necessary for the package to work.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: But that's not the question anyway.