# How to program mathematica (simple example)

Tags: physics, code-request

How do I program mathematica to perform basic second quantization operation of creation and annihilation operators such as c† and commutation rules for c†c.   I know that out there there are libraries (.m files) but I am looking for simple programming examples (.m files ?) so that I can  do my own.

I am trying to create operators such as creation operator and annihilation operator and Symbol dagger.  How to create new function and rules in mathematica. Also Green function advanced or (G^a) etc.

Just few and simple example

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [Notation Package tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html). Also the [non-commutative product](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) might be useful for expressing quantum operators.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125579/package-organization

Answer (score 1):

This is something I made mostly to learn the language rather than have something that I would use heavily. I don't claim it to be an efficient or even correct implementation of some simple quantum operators, but nevertheless I hope it can help.

I want to define a new head `Operator`, and a multiplication operation such that all the terms which do not contain the head `Operator` explicitly are factored out, leaving only the `Operator` objects inside. This could be done as follows.

```
Remove[ourTimes, Operator];

Format[Operator[a_]] := OverHat[a];
Format[ourTimes[a__]] := AngleBracket[Row@List[a]];

ourTimes[a___, b__, c___] /; FreeQ[{b}, Operator] := 
Times[b, ourTimes[a, c]];

ourTimes[a___, b_ + c__, d___] := 
ourTimes[a, b, d] + 
ourTimes[a, Plus[c], d];
ourTimes[a___, b_.*(x_Operator + c__), d___] := 
ourTimes[a, b*x, d] + ourTimes[a, b*Plus[c], d];
ourTimes[a___, b_.*x_Operator + c__, d___] := 
ourTimes[a, b*x, d] + ourTimes[a, Plus[c], d];

ourTimes[a___, b__*x__Operator, d___] /; FreeQ[{b}, Operator] := 
Times[b, ourTimes[a, x, d]];

ourTimes[a___, ourTimes[b_, c__], d___] := 
ourTimes[a, b, c, d];

ourTimes[a___] /; FreeQ[{a}, Operator] := Times[a];

Attributes[ourTimes] = {Flat};
```

We can try it out by defining the following operators (results omitted, you can try these yourself).

```
q = (Operator[a] + Operator[a^\[Dagger]])/Sqrt[2 \[Omega]];
p = -I (Operator[a] - Operator[a^\[Dagger]])*Sqrt[\[Omega]/2];

ourTimes[q, p]
ourTimes[q, q] - Expand[ourTimes[q]*ourTimes[q]]
```

To get a numeric value as a final result, you could interpret expressions where `ourTimes` contains only operator arguments as expectation values, then define a list of rules that transform the expectation values. You could even define different rule sets for different states to get different results depending on which states you assume to have.

I made the example above when reading [Leonid's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/), section 4.3.6., which should also offer some insight into how the code above works. I recommend the book to you, it's a good read.