# Multilevel organization of a package

Tags: packages

When writing a Mathematica package MyPackage, with functions f1, f2 and f3, one can use the template:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];

f1::usage = "f1[] ....";

f2::usage = "f2[] ....";

Begin["`Private`"];

f1[]:= code for f1

f2[]:= code for f2

f3[]:= code for f3 (not visible as only in the private context)

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

My question is linked to the structuration of package. In fact, instead of having a lot of functions in a package, i would like to build subpackages with this kind of structure.

```
MyPackage
   SubMyPackage1
       Function1
       Function2
   SubMyPackage2
       Function1
       Function2
       Function3
       Function3
...
```

Can you help me to define a robust template to make and use a package with different levels of subpackages ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up such a hierarchy fairly easily.

One way is hinted at by the supplied packages (eg NumericalCalculus). Simply define your packages and `Get[]` them using a 'master' package.

A similar method is to ensure that all dependent packages are loaded with the package definition

```
BeginPackage["MyMain`Package`", {"MyMain`SecondPackage`","MyMain`ThirdPackage`""MyMain`FourthPackage`"}]
```

as required.

This question may be answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/creating-mathematica-packages?rq=1).