# Context issues when using NDSolve and rule substitutions in a package

Tags: differential-equations, packages, contexts

I have a `.wl` package and a demo `.nb` notebook. The package file is `testPackage.wl` and it consists of:

```
BeginPackage["testPackage`"]

testIntegrator::usage = 
"Demonstrates an issue with Context in my package"


Begin["`Private`"]

testIntegrator[ v_]:=
Module[
    {vSub,odes,vp},
    vSub=(v/.{x->x[t]});
    odes={
    x'[t]==vSub,
    x[0]==x0
    };
    vp=x[t]/.ParametricNDSolve[
    odes,
    x[t],
    {t,0,1},
    {x0}];
    vp
]


End[]

EndPackage[]
```

The notebook that runs this code is `demos.nb` and it consists of

```
<< testPackage.wl
pf = testIntegrator[Exp[-x]]
Plot[pf[.1], {t, 0, 1}]
```

When I run the above notebook, it returns a non-usable ParametricFunction object, which appears to be due to issues with the context of the dependent variables. The function looks like this

[image]

In comparison, if I define the function in the notebook itself (rather than in an external `.wl` file), I do not have this problem. The function correctly returns this output

[image]

How do I correctly handle the variable contexts when defining functions in an external package? I think that my variable substitution `(v/.{x->x[t]})` likely may be at fault, but I am unsure how to modify it.

Comment: I think the linked topic should answer all your doubts. Let me know if you disagree with marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the best solution is to re-design the function as

```
testIntegrator[v_, x_, t_]:= …
```

But if you insist on the original design, which is undoubtedly a bad design, then place a line `x;t;` before `` Begin["`Private`"] `` i.e.

```
…
x; t;
Begin["`Private`"]
…
```

Don't forget to restart the kernel or `` Remove[Global`x, Global`t] `` first.

BTW, if you just don't care about context, simply removing all the `BeginPackage`, `Begin`, `End`, `EndPackage` is also a possible solution.

You may check the following post for more information:

[Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/1871)

Comment: Thank you, I am new to best practices package design. Would you mind clarifying why the original design is bad? Is the idea that I should always make sure that all values at which the function is evaluated are explicit arguments? Or is using NDSolve within a function like this inherently a bad approach?

Comment: @wil3 The design is bad because, `x` and `t` are both frequently used variables, but your package monopolize them. “Is the idea that I should always make sure that all values at which the function is evaluated are explicit arguments? ” Not always. Another possible design is to make the variable unique enough. (Remember those system variables start with `$`?  )

Comment: @wil3 have you read the topic I linked below your question?