# Basic mathematica coding package examples

Tags: functions, packages

Since Google and Mathematica documentation has proven utterly useless at answering my question...

Does ANYONE have some BASIC examples of how to code up a package? For my course work, I have to create a critical points package with modules that apply the second derivative test and first derivative test.

And I have been unable to find even a SIMPLE example of how to write a package that can accept a function as a parameter and contains multiple modules.

I have experience coding in C++ and Java, but ZERO experience with Mathematica.

Comment: I just googled `how to make a package in mathematica` and gots lots of links with examples? The first link shows one package with 2 modules in it.

Comment: Welcome!  You will find many of your questions already answered here.  You may find it quicker to first learn to find the critical points with Mathematica, then learn how to create functions that find the CPs, then put the functions into a package.  Note that terms like Package and Module have very specific meanings in Mathematica.  When you are ready, there are some simple examples of creating packages at [Creating a Mathematica Package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/creating-mathematica-packages).

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/creating-mathematica-packages

Comment: Please check: [tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html)