# How can I commit files to Github by Mathematica?

Tags: web-access

## How can I publish Notebooks to Github via using Mathematica?

---

I'm on windows 8.1 x64,  *Mathematica*  9.

How can I upload the current notebook to Github?

My function expected is: `Notebook2Github[EvaluationNotebook[]]`

Now I've installed Github on Windows, and have one [test page](http://hypergroups.github.io/)

The **annoying** thing is that each time I added/modified a new file in the destination folder(`E:\Users\HyperGroups\Documents\GitHub\hypergroups.github.com`), I should open GitHub, and add something into the `uncommitted changes` fields and click the `sync` button(shown in the picture)

[image]

How can I avoid doing that and complete all such things by the function `Notebook2Github`.

---

#### My tries in Git Shell

I can use the following commands in the GitShell.

`git add [new file]` /`git commit`  and `git push` and the new file will be updated to GitHub.

Comment: Making a full fledged VCS client in _Mathematica_ is no easy task and you're asking an awful lot without showing any effort. I know that Leonid is working on such a project to share code/notebooks via gists (in github) and that is not a trivial task even for him. Besides, there are tools that are much better for git than _Mathematica_ and tailored to work with Github/Bitbucket that you shouldn't be reinventing hte wheel... Since you already know that _Mathematica_ can run things from the command line, what's stopping you from trying it out? You just need to learn the appropriate git commands.

Comment: @rm-rf I donot know how to call the GitShell in Mathematica, I only know how to call an C .exe program(generated by CCompiler) with some arguments and import the results.

Comment: Your issue here mainly seems to be an unfamiliarity with git. Perhaps you should start with a good git guide like [this one](http://git-scm.com/book). Try following through those examples with some dummy repos. Forget _Mathematica_ when doing all this. Once you've learnt git, you can read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26180/5) for some general info on git + notebooks/m-files.

Comment: @rm-rf ah, ok, thanks,--- yes, I signed up the Git account this morning __@@

Comment: @rm-rf The two main problems for me so far have been the lack of time (by far, the worst one), and the right design choices, in terms of usability. I am on vacation right now, so I hope to move things along. The VCS itself has been basically ready for quite some time, but I was making a mistake of over-generalizing things, and also it wasn't clear for me until recently how to connect that seamlessly to the standard notebook-based workflow usual for most users. I seem to have some good ideas now, which should be not too hard to implement, so hopefully soon enough I will be able to say more.

Comment: @rm-rf happy to find/work out a solution. Maybe could be made more easily?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin happy to find/work out a solution. Maybe could be made more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Publish to GitHub with Mathematica on Windows

---

I'm on windows 8.1

Let's just concentrate on how to commit the files. [git push]

## Method

---

### 1 Auto type username and password

---

download an [assistant tool小助手](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories)[Permanently authenticating with Git repositories]

my git-credential-winstore.exe is put and installed here

```
"E:\\Users\\Hyper\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_\fed20eba68b3e238e49a47cdfed0a45783d93651\\bin"
```

### 2 Put commands in the .bat file

---

Put the commands set used in GitShell in the .bat file of the portable version of GitHub.

```
batFile =   "E:\\Users\\Hyper\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_\fed20eba68b3e238e49a47cdfed0a45783d93651\\git-cmd.bat";

batSample =   "@rem Do not use \"echo off\" to not affect any child calls.  @setlocal    @rem Get the abolute path to the current directory, which is \assumed to be the  @rem Git installation root.  @for /F \"delims=\" %%I in (\"%~dp0\") do @set git_install_root=%%~fI  @set PATH=%git_install_root%\\bin;%git_install_root%\\mingw\\bin;%\git_install_root%\\cmd;%PATH%    @if not exist \"%HOME%\" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%  @if not exist \"%HOME%\" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%    @set PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh  @if not defined TERM set TERM=msys    @cd %HOME%  ::@start %COMSPEC%    ::@start \"\" cmd /k @cd /d documents\\github && @git    cd /d documents\\github\\hypergroups.github.com  ";

commandsSet = "git add .  git commit -a -m \"" <> windowTitle[EvaluationNotebook[]] <> "\"  git push"

(*
    git add .git commit -a -m "Publish to GitHub with Mathematica on Windows"git push
*)

batFileToExport = batSample <> commandsSet(*<>"\npause"*);

Export["bat.txt", batFileToExport];DeleteFile@batFile;CopyFile["bat.txt", batFile];
```

### 3 Run the .bat file

[image]

---

```
batFile // SystemOpen
```

## References

---

Also, I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475333/how-can-i-convert-gitshells-commands-into-an-bat-file)

I've redone this succesfully.

Comment: [I'm not sure whether this is useful now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password)

Answer (score 13):

Another option for individual files and stuff is to use the GitHub API with a [custom plug-in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205) to the [built-in service connection framework](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceConnect.html).

Here's a service connection I wrote for it:

```
PacletInstall["ServiceConnection_GitHub",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

Then we load it like this:

```
$gh = ServiceConnect@"GitHub"
```

[image: github connection]

We can see what requests are there:

```
In[73]:= $gh["Requests"]

Out[73]= {"AddFile", "ArchiveLink", "Authentication", "BranchInfo", \
"BranchProtection", "CreateOrganizationRepository", \
"CreateRepository", "DeleteFile", "DeleteRepository", \
"EditRepository", "ID", "ImportFile", "Information", "ListBranches", \
"ListMyRepositories", "ListOrganizationRepositories", \
"ListRepositories", "ListUserRepositories", "Name", "RawRequests", \
"ReadMeContents", "RemoveBranchProtection", "RepositoryContributors", \
"RepositoryInfo", "RepositoryLanguages", "RepositoryTags", \
"RepositoryTeams", "RequestData", "RequestParameters", \
"SetBranchProtection", "UpdateFile"}
```

So we'll start by making a testing repo. First we'll see what we need:

```
In[74]:= $gh["RequestParameters", 
  "Request" -> "CreateRepository"]["Required"]

Out[74]= {"name"}
```

So we'll give it a name like api-testing-repo:

```
In[80]:= $gh["CreateRepository", "name" -> "api-testing-repo"][{"id", 
  "name"}]//Normal

Out[80]= <|"id" -> 93099247, "name" -> "api-testing-repo"|>
```

Then we upload a file (note that it has to be Base64 encoded):

```
$gh[
  "AddFile",
  "user" -> "b3m2a1",
  "repo" -> "api-testing-repo",
  "path" -> "test.txt",
  "content" -> Developer`EncodeBase64@"file_text_goes_here",
  "message" -> "file upload test"
  ]["content", "sha"]
```

And we can see it exists:

[image: file exists]

Now we'll delete the file:

```
$gh[
 "DeleteFile",
 "user" -> "b3m2a1",
 "repo" -> "api-testing-repo",
 "path" -> "test.txt",
 "sha" -> "6e560c960830951d7d77b0960cd961173ed86ce0",
 "message" -> "file delete test"
 ]
```

And we'll see it no longer exists:

[image: no more file]

And now for good measure we delete the repo:

```
$gh[
 "DeleteRepository",
 "user" -> "b3m2a1",
 "repo" -> "api-testing-repo"
 ]
```

Comment: This is very interesting

Comment: @faysou Glad to hear it. If you're interested in how I set this up here's the template notebook: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/git_hub_service_template

Comment: Neat! Is this usable with [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink)?

Comment: @J.M. I've never actually used GitLink myself. As I understand it, it's working at a `LibraryLink` level, while I was building on the `ServiceConnect` framework. Presumably, though, one could use this service connection to build a repo, then use `GitLink` to do the rest. I do this myself when building new paclets, but using Git through `RunProcess` rather `GitLink`.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the relation between service and the public api of GitHub. How can one e.g. `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest`?

Comment: @Kuba I cooked different things in, but unfortunately I haven't migrated everything in my BTools GitHub connection to this. I can give that a bit of work when I update my BTools docs (since it's super fast to add functions). In the meantime this will work: ``so["RepositoryInfo", "user" -> "b3m2a1", "repo" -> "mathematica-BTools/releases/latest"]`` I've been using long names so as to make it a little simpler to understand how the connection works for those without knowledge of the API.