# importing mathematica files into Github

Tags: import

I'm going to import my files in Mathematica (.nb) into my Github profile. Is there any method to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I understand that this may not be clear to a beginner, but how to use GitHub and git doesn't depend on what language you program in. The first thing you need to do it learn the basics of using GitHub and git. There are many tutorials other there. If after this you still have questions about a Mathematica-specific workflow, feel free to ask a new question. But please be specific about what problem you encountered.

Comment: Tip: Since `.nb` files are not written by hand, they are not a very good fit for git. Plain text `.m` or `.wl` files can reap all benefits, but not `.nb`.

Comment: I agree with @Szabolcs and I also vote to close this question as off-topic

Comment: @Szabolcs Since I couldn't find the answer in github tutorials, I tempted to ask my question here!... As you may know, importing `.py` or `.ipynb` files are easy in github, but `.nb` files are tricky. Your suggestion for using `.m` or `.wl` is good but it still doesn't work like `.py`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put Mathematica Notebooks and packages on Github?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136634/how-to-put-mathematica-notebooks-and-packages-on-github). Also see: [How can I commit files to Github by Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30821/27951) and [What are the recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26174/27951).

Comment: @حسینسلحشور _all_ plain-text files work fine through Git. If you issue is just that it doesn't display like it does in the regular Mathematica front-end, well that's beyond our control. Only GitHub can change that.