# Creating a contingency table

Tags: functions, matrix, probability-or-statistics

I need help in creating a function for a contingency table... I imagined to create it like this...

```
Contingency[a_] := 
 Module[{n = Dimensions[a][[1]], m = Dimensions[a][[2]], ...},
  ...
  ]
```

`a` is a $n \times m$ matrix with frequency distribution.

Is this kinda way possible?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41450)

Comment: related question dont help!

Comment: I didn't say there was a solution there, only that it was related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Links to implementations

See the bottom of this package, [CrossTabulate.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/CrossTabulate.m) for different implementations (`CrossTabulate`):

- one is based on `Tally`, `GatherBy`, and `SparseArray`,
- the other is based in R' `xtabs` (via RLink).

The function `CrossTensorate` generalizes the contingency value finding.

The making of contingency matrices and tensors with those functions is discussed in these posts:

- ["Contingency tables creation examples" at WordPress](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/contingency-tables-creation-examples/),
- ["Contingency tables creation examples" at community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/933964).

Here is [an alternative implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101951)
at Stack Overflow by Mr.Wizard.

### Code to try

#### Get package

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/CrossTabulate.m"]
```

#### Get data

```
titanicData = 
  Flatten@*List @@@ 
   ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "Data"];
titanicData = DeleteCases[titanicData, {___, _Missing, ___}];

titanicColumnNames = 
  Flatten@*List @@ 
   ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "VariableDescriptions"];
aTitanicColumnNames = 
  AssociationThread[
   titanicColumnNames -> Range[Length[titanicColumnNames]]];
```

#### Make a contingency matrix

```
ctCounts = 
  CrossTabulate[
   titanicData[[All, 
     aTitanicColumnNames /@ {"passenger class", "passenger survival"}]]];

MatrixForm[ctCounts]
```

[image]

#### Make a contingency tensor (using a formula)

```
ctRes = CrossTensorate[
   Count == 
    "passenger survival" + "passenger sex" + "passenger class", 
   titanicData, aTitanicColumnNames];
MatrixForm[ctRes]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a function in Wolfram Function Repository for making contingency tables: [`CrossTabulate`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CrossTabulate).

[image]

Comment: See also the paclet ["DataReshapers"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/DataReshapers/).