# GroupBy dataset values and length

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset, and I want to group by one of my columns, and then show the Length of another set of columns for each group. For example:

```
letter color
 a     red
 a     red
 a     blue
 b     blue
```

I want my new dataset to show:

```
    red blue
a    2   1
b    0   1
```

where red and blue are now column headers.

What code can I use to do this?

Comment: related: [Creating a contingency table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153734/125)

Answer (score 7):

Starting with the dataset from the question:

```
dataset =
  {{"a", "red"}, {"a", "red"}, {"a", "blue"}, {"b", "blue"}} //
    Query[Dataset, AssociationThread[{"letter", "color"} -> #]&]
```

[image: input dataset]

... then we can get the desired result as follows:

```
dataset[
  KeyUnion[#, 0&]& /* (GroupBy[#, Key["letter"] -> KeyDrop["letter"], Merge[Total]]&)
, <|"letter" -> #letter, #color -> 1|>&
]
```

[image: result dataset]

This works as follows:

1. `<|"letter" -> #letter, #color -> 1|>&` is used to set the count of each row's color to one.
2. `KeyUnion` is used to introduce a count of zero for colors missing from each row.
3. `GroupBy` is used to group the rows together by letter and `Total` the color counts.

Answer (score 4):

```
dt = {{letter, color}, {a, red}, {a, red}, {a , blue}, {b, blue}}; 
TableForm[Outer[Count[dt[[2 ;;]], {##}] &, ## & @@ #], 
    TableHeadings -> #] &[DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose[dt[[2 ;;]]]] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{ccc}
>   & \text{red} & \text{blue} \\
>  a & 2 & 1 \\
>  b & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Thanks - Is there any way to do this in dataset form as well, or does it have to be in list and table form?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie, could you add the `Dataset` input form of the example to you post?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Taking @WReach `Dataset` definition.

```
dataset =
  {{"a", "red"}, {"a", "red"}, {"a", "blue"}, {"b", "blue"}} //
    Query[Dataset, AssociationThread[{"letter", "color"} -> #]&]
```

Then

```
dataset[GroupBy[{#["color"] &, #["letter"] &}] /*
  Transpose /*
  ReplaceAll[_Missing -> 0],
 All,
 Length]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultds = <|"blue" -> 0, "red" -> 0|>;

dataset[GroupBy[#, Key@"letter" -> Key@"color", 
   (Join[defaultds, #] &)@GroupBy[#, Identity, Length] &] &]
```

> [image: Blockquote]