# Constructing transition probability matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following list:

```
x={"A", "A", "A", "E", "D", "D", "D", "C", "B", "E", "E", "E", "D", \
"B", "A", "D", "B", "E", "C", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", \
"C", "D", "D", "E"}
```

I want to make the Markov transition probability matrix of first order. To do so I have started by writing:

```
Partition[x, 2, 1] // Sort // Counts
```

This will give:

```
<|{"A", "A"} -> 5, {"A", "C"} -> 1, {"A", "D"} -> 2, {"A", "E"} -> 
  1, {"B", "A"} -> 1, {"B", "E"} -> 2, {"C", "A"} -> 1, {"C", "B"} -> 
  1, {"C", "C"} -> 2, {"C", "D"} -> 1, {"D", "A"} -> 1, {"D", "B"} -> 
  2, {"D", "C"} -> 1, {"D", "D"} -> 3, {"D", "E"} -> 1, {"E", "C"} -> 
  1, {"E", "D"} -> 2, {"E", "E"} -> 2|>
```

above shows the frequencies of state transition A to A, A to B, A to C, A to D and A to E and so on for other letters, I wonder how can I show this result as a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SparseArray` with additive assembly as follows:

```
x = RandomChoice[Alphabet["English", "IndexCharacters"], 1000000];
data = Flatten[ToCharacterCode[x]] - (ToCharacterCode["A"][[1]] - 1); // AbsoluteTiming // First
A = With[{
 spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   (*switch to additive assembly*)
   SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
   
   (*assemble matrix*)
   SparseArray[
    Partition[data, 2, 1] -> 1, 
    Max[data] {1, 1}
    ]
   
   , 
   (*reset "SparseArrayOptions" to previous value*)
   SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
  ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.739454
>
> 0.114682

## Remarks

- As the timings suggest, it is worthwhile to avoid strings in the first place.
- Formerly, I used `LetterNumber`, but `ToCharacterCode` is much, much faster.
- It is `"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total` which enables summing of entries. `Count` is not needed anymore. `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` might speed up things a bit if `x` is *very* long. The other hokus-pokus is for making things bulletproof against aborts (i.e., options are reset even if computations are interrupted). See also [(37566)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37566) and [(136017)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136017).

Comment: That `"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total` is a nice trick!

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisK. You know, I could not live without the `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` option.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for this, I turned this into matrix form using //MatrixForm and I got the answer I was after, I wonder if it is possible to use the same for different size of partition and offsets? Such as SparseArray[
 Partition[Developer`ToPackedArray[LetterNumber[x]], 3, 1] -> 1] in that case I get wrong matrix positions

Comment: You may try this, instead: ``A = With[{
   data = Developer`ToPackedArray[LetterNumber[x]],
   spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]
   }, Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions[
    "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}], 
   SparseArray[Partition[data, 3, 1] -> 1, Max[data] {1, 1, 1}],
   SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]``. It prescribes the tensor dimensions explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the package [CrossTabulate.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/CrossTabulate.m). (More detailed references are given in [this MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153737/34008).)

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/CrossTabulate.m"]

cmat = CrossTabulate[Partition[x, 2, 1]];

MatrixForm[cmat]
```

[image]

```
cmat["SparseMatrix"] = cmat["SparseMatrix"]/Total[cmat["SparseMatrix"], {2}];
MatrixForm[cmat]
```

[image]

```
ArrayRules[cmat["SparseMatrix"]]

(* {{1, 1} -> 5/9, {1, 5} -> 1/9, {1, 4} -> 2/9, {1, 3} -> 1/
  9, {2, 5} -> 2/3, {2, 1} -> 1/3, {3, 2} -> 1/5, {3, 1} -> 1/
  5, {3, 3} -> 2/5, {3, 4} -> 1/5, {4, 4} -> 3/8, {4, 3} -> 1/
  8, {4, 2} -> 1/4, {4, 1} -> 1/8, {4, 5} -> 1/8, {5, 4} -> 2/
  5, {5, 5} -> 2/5, {5, 3} -> 1/5, {_, _} -> 0} *)
```

Comment: I like to create a transition matrix using a weighted, directed graph with the domain of weights, [0, 1.5]. My states will be 7 equal length subsets of the domain and the transition matrix will have the number of binary links in each subset. I could have asked a new question but then I realized that instead of letters I wanted to use subsets. I have two directed graphs (time t and t+1) to start with the exercise. But you may just create two randreal graphs to answer. Can you help me?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Yes, please post a new MSE question. (The possible answers are too long to be just comments...)

Comment: I have posted a new question yesterday after sending you my request. I realized that the answers are too long for comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `EstimatedProcess` and `MarkovProcessProperties` as follows:

```
states = DeleteDuplicates[x];
ordering = Ordering[states]; 
data = ArrayComponents @ x ;
estproc = EstimatedProcess[data, DiscreteMarkovProcess[Length@states]];
tm = MarkovProcessProperties[estproc, "TransitionMatrix"][[ordering, ordering]] 

TeXForm[TableForm[tm, TableHeadings -> {states[[ordering]], states[[ordering]]}]]
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccc}
>   & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
>  \text{A} & \frac{5}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
>  \text{B} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\
>  \text{C} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
>  \text{D} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} \\
>  \text{E} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: This is very neat thank you what if you want to find the same transition probability matrix for higher orders? For example in the second order case one would have the same columns namely, A, B, C, D and E and 5^2 rows {AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,BA,...,EA,EB,EC,ED,EE}.

Comment: @William, that's a good question. Can't think of a way off the top of my head.

Comment: @William if you have a follow up  question it's best to ask a new question that links to this one.