# Constructing higher order transition probability matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, markov-chains, markov-process

Recently I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179613/constructing-transition-probability-matrix/179674#179674) about how to construct a transition probability matrix given the following list:

```
x = {"A", "A", "A", "E", "D", "D", "D", "C", "B", "E", "E", "E", "D", 
  "B", "A", "D", "B", "E", "C", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
  "C", "C", "D", "D", "E"}
```

For which one can get the following matrix: (see the detail from the previous question)

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
& \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
\text{A} & \frac{5}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
\text{B} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\
\text{C} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
\text{D} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} \\
\text{E} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
\end{array}$$

above is equivalent of partitioning list $x$ into sublists with size 2 and offset of 1, then counting each element and divide it by the sum of the row. The command to find the right partition is `Partition[x, 2, 1]` (again I refer you to the previous question). Now what if we want to find the higher order transition matrix? For example the second order would be `Partition[x, 3, 1]` and the expected matrix shall look like:

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
   & A & B & C & D &E \\
AA & P_{AA,A} & P_{AA,B} & P_{AA,C} & P_{AA,D} &P_{AA,E}\\
AB & P_{AB,A} & P_{AB,B} & P_{AB,C} & P_{AB,D} &P_{AB,E}\\
AC & P_{AC,A} & P_{AC,B} & P_{AC,C} & P_{AC,D} &P_{AC,E}\\
AD & P_{AD,A} & P_{AD,B} & P_{AD,C} & P_{AD,D} &P_{AD,E}\\
AE & P_{AE,A} & P_{AE,B} & P_{AE,C} & P_{AE,D} &P_{AE,E}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots  &\vdots & \vdots\\ 
EC & P_{EC,A} & P_{EC,B} & P_{EC,C} & P_{EC,D} &P_{EC,E}\\
ED &P_{ED,A} & P_{ED,B} & P_{ED,C} & P_{ED,D} &P_{ED,E}\\
EE & P_{EE,A} & P_{EE,B} & P_{EE,C} & P_{EE,D} &P_{EE,E}\\
\end{array}$$

In general the dimension of the matrix follows $\{|S|^n,|S|\}$, where n is the order of the Markov chain.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @rhermans it was really bugging me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code is just brute-force. But at least yields the expected results. Also, it can be used for any order.

The first parameter is the data. The second parameter is the order.

```
probM[data_, ord_] := 
 Module[{uniques = Union[data], acc = 0, len, trans, trPre, tData, 
   toCount, toGather, toNormalize},
  trans = Dispatch@Thread[uniques -> Range[len = Length[uniques]]];
  trPre = Dispatch@Flatten[Array[{##} -> ++acc &, ConstantArray[len, ord]]];
  tData = Replace[data, trans, {1}];
  toCount = Partition[tData, ord + 1, 1];
  toGather = Map[{Replace[#[[1, ;; -2]], trPre], #[[1, -1]]} -> #[[2]] &, 
    Tally[toCount]];
  toNormalize = GatherBy[toGather, #[[1, 1]] &];
  SparseArray[
   Flatten@Map[
     With[{tot = 1/Plus @@ #[[All, 2]]}, 
       Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] tot &, #]] &, toNormalize]]];
```

Let us check the dimensions of the first three orders.

```
Table[probM[x, i] // Dimensions, {i, 3}]
(*{{5, 5}, {25, 5}, {125, 5}}*)
```

As for the efficiency of `probM`, I tried replacing some of the `Map` with `ParallelMap` but it did not yield any improvement. You might want to combine with niceties from the other answer. For example, use `ArrayComponents` instead of dispatch tables.

In any case, check the second order table:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
 \text{AA} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\
 \text{AB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{AC} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{AD} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{AE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \text{BA} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \text{BB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{BC} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{BD} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{BE} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \text{CA} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \text{CB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{CC} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \text{CD} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \text{CE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{DA} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{DB} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \text{DC} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{DD} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \text{DE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{EA} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{EB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{EC} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{ED} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \text{EE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, what command did you use to get the final table? when I run your code I get {{5, 5}, {22, 5}, {109, 5}}

Comment: @William Try `probM[x, 2] // MatrixForm`. As for your result, it seems that you run `Table[probM[x, i] // Dimensions, {i, 3}]`. But that should have returned `{{5, 5}, {25, 5}, {125, 5}}`. What version of MMA are you running? Mine is 9.0.

Comment: Perfect, and how can I change the orders (this is second order, if I want to check the code with 1, 3 and other orders)? and the offset (possibly)?

Comment: I am using 8.0 ver

Comment: @William I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** Using `EmpiricalDistribution` and `MarginalDistribution` to compute the conditional probabilities:

```
ClearAll[transitionProb]
transitionProb[step_: 1][x_] := Module[{states = DeleteDuplicates@x, 
   ed = EmpiricalDistribution[Partition[ArrayComponents @ x, step + 1, 1]], 
   ordering, tuples, md, condpdF},
  ordering = Ordering[states]; tuples = Tuples[ordering, step];
  md = MarginalDistribution[ed, Range[step]];
  condpdF[u__, w_] := If[PDF[md, {u}] === 0, 0, PDF[ed, {u, w}]/PDF[md, {u}]];
  Prepend[{Row @ states[[{##}]], 
      ## & @@ Table[## & @@ condpdF[##, i], {i, ordering}]} & @@@ tuples, 
   Prepend[states[[ordering]], ""]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
transitionProb[2][x] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
> \hline
>  \text{A}\text{A} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\
> \hline
>  \text{A}\text{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{A}\text{C} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{A}\text{D} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{A}\text{E} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{B}\text{A} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{B}\text{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{B}\text{C} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{B}\text{D} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{B}\text{E} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
> \hline
>  \text{C}\text{A} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{C}\text{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \hline
>  \text{C}\text{C} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{C}\text{D} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{C}\text{E} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{D}\text{A} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{D}\text{B} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
> \hline
>  \text{D}\text{C} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{D}\text{D} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
> \hline
>  \text{D}\text{E} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{E}\text{A} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{E}\text{B} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{E}\text{C} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{E}\text{D} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{E}\text{E} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

```
transitionProb[1][x] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
> \hline
>  \text{A} & \frac{5}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
> \hline
>  \text{B} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\
> \hline
>  \text{C} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{D} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} \\
> \hline
>  \text{E} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

**Original answer:**

```
states = DeleteDuplicates[x];
ordering = Ordering[states]; 
data = ArrayComponents@x ;
estproc = EstimatedProcess[data, DiscreteMarkovProcess[Length@states]];
tuples = Tuples[Range[5][[ordering]], {2}];
table = {Row@states[[{##}]], ## & @@ 
      Table[Probability[p[3] == s \[Conditioned] p[1] == # && p[2] == #2, 
        p \[Distributed] estproc], {s, Range[Length @ states]}]} & @@@ tuples ;

TeXForm @ Grid[Prepend[table, Prepend[states[[ordering]], ""]], Dividers -> All]
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} \\
> \hline
>  \text{AA} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{AB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{AC} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
> \hline
>  \text{AD} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} \\
> \hline
>  \text{AE} & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{BA} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{BB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{BC} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{BD} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{BE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{CA} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{CB} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{CC} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
> \hline
>  \text{CD} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} \\
> \hline
>  \text{CE} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{DA} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{DB} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{DC} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
> \hline
>  \text{DD} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} \\
> \hline
>  \text{DE} & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{EA} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{EB} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \hline
>  \text{EC} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
> \hline
>  \text{ED} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} \\
> \hline
>  \text{EE} & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, however as a check I tried 'Partition[x, 3, 1] // Counts' which shows that I have 3 AAA instead of 5, this happens all over the table my worry is that the state ordering and data which you defined are not matched, for example in ordering E has value of 5, while in data it is 2.

Comment: @William, re ordering of states, that's why we sort them using `ordering` so that `2` corresponds to `E`. Re the discrepancy between `Partition[x, 3, 1] // Counts`  and the `Prob[A|AA]` in the table above, i think it is because `table` is based on the TransitionMatrix of  `estproc` and `estproc`  is based on one-step  transitions (`Partition[x,2,1]`).

Comment: So basically DiscreteMarkovProcess doesn't have a memory, because in second order the transition is remembering the two steps behind that's why it is AA,A and not for example A,A,A, interesting.

Comment: @William, please see the update.

Comment: thank you @kglr, it indeed works fine and is shorter yet if you change the variable in Partition[data, 3, 1] for example to Partition[data, 2, 1] or else, the final table will not come out appropriate. I think hector's answer is good because you can change the order

Answer (score 4):

As a variant of [my answer to the linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179619), the following should work correctly and efficiently.

Some random data to work with:

```
x = RandomChoice[Alphabet["English", "IndexCharacters"], 1000000];
```

Creating the probability tensor `P`:

```
n = 2;
data = Flatten[ToCharacterCode[x]] - (ToCharacterCode["A"][[1]] - 1); // AbsoluteTiming // First
A = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]}, 
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      (*switch to additive assembly*)
      SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],

      (*assemble matrix*)
      SparseArray[Partition[data, n + 1, 1] -> 1, ConstantArray[Max[data], n + 1] ],

      (*reset "SparseArrayOptions" to previous value*)
      SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
P = #/N[Total[Abs[#], {n + 1}] /. 0 -> 1] &@Flatten[A, n - 1];
```

> 0.717521
>
> 0.184357

The row labels of `P` should be

```
Tuples[Sort[DeleteDuplicates[x]], n]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CrossTensorate` from the package [CrossTabulate.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/CrossTabulate.m), which I used and referenced in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179621/34008) of the previous question.

The making of contingency tensors with that function is discussed in this blog post: ["Contingency tables creation examples"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/contingency-tables-creation-examples/).

In general, though, I would say it is better to use [Tries with Frequencies](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2017/01/31/tries-with-frequencies-in-java/) or nested associations.

```
tmat3 = CrossTensorate[Count == 1 + 2 + 3, Partition[x, 3, 1]];

tmat4 = CrossTensorate[Count == 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, Partition[x, 4, 1]];

tmat3["XTABTensor"] = #/(Total[#, {Length[Dimensions[#]]}] /. {0 -> 1}) &@tmat3["XTABTensor"];
tmat4["XTABTensor"] = #/(Total[#, {Length[Dimensions[#]]}] /. {0 -> 1}) &@tmat4["XTABTensor"];

Grid[{{"tmat3", "tmat4"}, {MatrixForm[tmat3], MatrixForm[tmat4]}}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayRules[tmat3["XTABTensor"]]

(* {{1, 1, 1} -> 3/5, {1, 1, 5} -> 1/5, {1, 5, 4} -> 
  1, {1, 4, 2} -> 1/2, {1, 4, 1} -> 1/2, {1, 1, 3} -> 1/
  5, {1, 3, 3} -> 1, {2, 5, 5} -> 1/2, {2, 1, 4} -> 1, {2, 5, 3} -> 1/
  2, {3, 2, 5} -> 1, {3, 1, 4} -> 1, {3, 3, 3} -> 1/2, {3, 3, 4} -> 1/
  2, {3, 4, 4} -> 1, {4, 4, 4} -> 1/3, {4, 4, 3} -> 1/3, {4, 3, 2} -> 
  1, {4, 2, 1} -> 1/2, {4, 2, 5} -> 1/2, {4, 1, 1} -> 1, {4, 4, 5} -> 
  1/3, {5, 4, 4} -> 1/2, {5, 5, 5} -> 1/2, {5, 5, 4} -> 1/
  2, {5, 4, 2} -> 1/2, {5, 3, 1} -> 1, {_, _, _} -> 0} *)
```