# Computation of 1- and 2-sided p-values for Fisher's Exact test for 2x2 table based on Monte Carlo

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I am looking for code to compute the 1- and 2-sided p-value for Fisher's Exact test for 2x2 tables based on Monte Carlo (bootstrap simulations).

For larger 2x2 crosstabulation tables, the exact p-value can often not be computed due to the large amount of computations.

Asymptotically p-values are often quite inaccurate.

Therefore, I would like to compute the p-values based on Monte Carlo.

Comment: So, have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41450) already?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I did. I already applied the suggested function and found that there is an error. Unfortunately, it does not properly for all cases.