# Mathematica Syntax Coloring in GitHub README

Tags: packages

GitHub doesn't auto-detect and color Mathematica code in its markdown. Can we make it do so?

This may be trivial, but [many](https://github.com/lshifr/ProjectInstaller) [README](https://github.com/lshifr/CodeFormatter) [files](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) don't seem to have it.

Comment: My README files actually have highlighting ;).

Comment: @jkuczm Good to know. I'll add that as a note. (I must have missed the purple on the `Get`)

Answer (score 17):

It seems to have been possible at least [since March 16th 2016](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor/grammars) and probably earlier (thanks to jkuczm) I found it [here](https://github.com/wolfram/Demonstrations/blob/master/RadiusAndTemperatureOfMainSequenceStars.md) (cannot remember how I ended up there). Here's [another example](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaOptionsValidation) using it.

If we look at [how that works](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wolfram/Demonstrations/master/RadiusAndTemperatureOfMainSequenceStars.md), though, we see this:

````
```Mathematica
Manipulate[
Module[{
r1=ClassVRadius[t1],
r2=ClassVRadius[t2],
r3=ClassVRadius[t3],
r4=ClassVRadius[t4],
r5=ClassVRadius[t5],
r6=ClassVRadius[t6],
r7=ClassVRadius[t7]},
Graphics3D[{
{ColorData["B...
etc.
```
````

And so just sticking your code in a block like that headed by Mathematica does it. I suppose this [should have been obvious](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code-and-syntax-highlighting). But maybe it's good to have it here for those of use who only use GitHub sparingly.

I used this trick [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools). Admittedly, the highlighting is poorly implemented and the colors are garish, but it's fun, at the very least. And maybe GitHub will improve it some day.

*One caveat:* As Szabolcs notes, this is not necessarily assured to work on other Markdown-using sites.

Comment: It may be good to note that only fenced code blocks support this, and fenced code blocks are not standard Markdown (hence may not render properly if the project is moved to a different hosting than GitHub).  [Also, I do not think this QA is off topic at all.]

Comment: @Szabolcs They are standard: http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#fenced-code-blocks

Comment: @Riking There seem to be disagreements and no proper standard ... Once I was told that some tool didn't support fenced code blocks because "it's not standard" and I believed it. Python markdown also doesn't support it, and the extension to add support did not play well with the syntax colouring extension I once tried to use.  So as you say, my statement about the standard was incorrect. But using this still have the risk I mentioned.  All implementations support indented code blocks, but several don't support fenced ones (e.g. the one used here on SE).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sorry I accidentally linked to highlight.js, while it seems that [GitHub uses Linguist](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: @jkuczm No problem. Still tracking down exactly when support was added. Just because.

Comment: Obvious corollary: Github's gist [supports](https://gist.github.com/drjjmc/fe09d3fd267c5d2a6112af0377da223f#file-scrapeinspireauthors-md) mma syntax highlighting with .nb file suffix, so a cheap way to add (*incredibly* garish) mathematica highlighting to one's  site... (e.g. [self-link](http://prettyquestions.com/presentations/2017_Strings/) )

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco interesting. Alternatively you can also use [halirutan's prettify.js](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting) plugin. That's what I do and I think what Szabolcs does.

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco wholly off topic, but related to your link, is [this post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1136952) on Wolfram Community where they provide another way to scrape inspire.

Comment: Wow: not just another way (downloading and parsing JSON snapshot) but provides a link to something I should've known about a long time ago: the official [inspire API page](https://inspirehep.net/info/hep/api), fantastic!  Thanks also for prettify link, set up direct comparison w/ gist: [here](http://prettyquestions.com/notes/2017_Mathematica_Prettifier/) .

Comment: I found your answer useful for answering this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/recommended-settings-for-git-when-using-with-mathematica-projects/204650#204650